# $n$ men and $n$ women form a queue, how many ways are there so that for every man, there are more women in front of him?

Tags: combinatorics

$n$ men and $n$ women form a queue. How many ways are there to line them up so that for every man, the number of women in front of him exceeds the number of men in front of him?

I don't know how to generalize.

- $n=1$: BA
- $n=2$: BABA, BBAA
- $n=3$: BBBAAA, BBAABA, BABBAA, BABABA, BBABAA

Comment: Please also put the full question in the body of your submission. Thank you!

Comment: You question is unclear. "there are more women in front of him" than what? Is the front of the queue the left end or the right end? Are the A's the men or the women?

Comment: @RosieF A queue is not a row

Comment: More women in front of him than men. Either left is front and B's are women or the opposite, doesn't matter which.

Comment: @fizis That doesn't make the question any more clear than before. What does the "there are more women in front of him" mean?

Comment: For every man in line, the number of women in front of him exceeds the number of men in front of him.

Comment: @Nitin Thank you, I think the question is very clear.

Comment: @5xum there are more women (than what do you think can fit here?) in front of him.

Comment: Where did you come across this question? Do you have any indication of whether the solution is easy or hard?

Comment: @EricAuld Thank you for editing the question. A friend of mine asked me this question in a different context, I reformulated it. I thought it is hard for me.

Comment: You can search the site for Catalan numbers or see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) to see why it is $\frac 1{n+1}{2n \choose n}$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you, the example in wiki is the same as mine.